# ASP.Net Web API - The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using the new MVC4 ASP.Net Web API system.

I am calling my API in a test project using WebClient. If I use GET or POST, it works fine. If I use anything else, I get Method Not Allowed. I am actually "faking" the method by injecting the following header. I am doing this because my end users will also have to do this due to the limitations of some firewalls.

I am calling the URL via IIS (i.e. not cassini) - e.g. http://localhost/MyAPI/api/Test

```
wc.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "PUT");
```

I tried adjusting the script mappings in IIS, but as there is no extension, I don't know what I am meant to be adjusting!

Any ideas?
Regards
Nick

Comment: How did you define your methods in your controller? Showing this in your question will help provide an answer. Did you use the attribute [HttpPut] on the method(s)?

Comment: I did exactly that - [HttpPut]

Comment: Actually, I have realised that it's causd by the X-HTTP-Method header. If I use WebRequest and set my "Method" to "PUT", it works fine. So now I'm more confused!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `X-HTTP-Method` (or `X-HTTP-Method-Override`) header is not supported out of the box by Web API. You will need to create a custom `DelegatingHandler` (below implementation assumes that you are making your request with `POST` method as it should be):

```
public class XHttpMethodDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static readonly string[] _allowedHttpMethods = { "PUT", "DELETE" };
    private static readonly string _httpMethodHeader = "X-HTTP-Method";

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.Headers.Contains(_httpMethodHeader))
        {
            string httpMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(_httpMethodHeader).FirstOrDefault();
            if (_allowedHttpMethods.Contains(httpMethod, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            request.Method = new HttpMethod(httpMethod);
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Now you just need to register your `DelegatingHandler` in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new XHttpMethodDelegatingHandler());
    ...
}
```

This should do the trick.